# Ubuntu:ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No route to host

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, git

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 and followed the help doc at github.com to set up git and connect to github but when I got to [step 5 of the set up ssh keys section](http://help.github.com/linux-set-up-git/) :Test everything out , When I used this command: `ssh -T git@github.com` I got an error:

> ssh: connect to host github.com port 22: No route to host

And I tried this command:

```
tcptraceroute github.com 22
```

Here is what I got:

```
Selected device eth0, address 222.20.58.XX(sorry...I masked part of my ip), port 33281 for outgoing packets
Tracing the path to github.com (207.97.227.239) on TCP port 22 (ssh), 30 hops max
 1  222.20.58.254  0.891 ms  0.850 ms  0.693 ms
 2  zxq-xs-h3c7510e.hust.edu.cn (115.156.255.137)  1.253 ms  1.569 ms  2.837 ms
 3  zxq-xs-rjs8606.hust.edu.cn (115.156.255.130)  0.729 ms  0.678 ms  0.629 ms
 4  115.156.255.174  0.794 ms  6.279 ms  16.569 ms
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
Destination not reached
```

It seems that the route is stopped at 115.156.255.174, which I don't know where it is.

Can anyone explain what's wrong here and how can I solve this?

Thanks very much.

Comment: Sure you actually have a working internet connection on that system? Could also be something blocking, maybe try: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/no-route-to-host-error-and-solution.html

Comment: @ckhan Yes, I have a working internet connection. I tried the solution 2, but it didn't work. About the solution one, I don't have the router information, I configured gateway and DNS though. Do I have to configure the router information?

Comment: If you can ping `github.com`, and you can visit www.github.com, then it would seem something is blocking 22.

Comment: @ckhan Yes, I can ping and visit it.

Comment: Your behind a something that is blocking port 22. Are you at work doing this?

Comment: @apesa no, I'm at school and I assume my university doesn't block it.

Comment: Assume otherwise, it is a security and standards issue to leave lower number ports open. I bet you need to proxy through. Ask your school  help desk or look for a FAQ online at your school. GitHub is huge and I am sure your not the only one.

Comment: @apesa I updated my question and added some information. Does that information means the port 22 is blocked by 115.156.255.174? Maybe that's a router?

Comment: I would say you're def blocked, zxq-xs-h3c7510e.hust.edu.cn resolves to a web login at HBC, Probably your schools ISP and I am sure they are not going to just crack it open for you. Like I said, your school should have a proxy for things like this or at least a policy/process. You always have to ask to have a port like 22 opened, or someone has already asked and a process exists, or you are not allowed to ssh through port 22 at hust.edu.cn

Answer (score 3):

just try to add the following to your ./.ssh/config:  ( touch one if having no this file )

```
host github.com
    hostname ssh.github.com
    port 443
```

this solution is from [Connection problems to github.com](http://devopsny.com/blog/2013/06/26/connection-problems-to-github-com/)

Comment: Still works 7 years later, thanks for posting.  On a corporate network behind a firewall